# How to exclude numbers from a solr text field?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to get some data from documents, I am using facet to get all the word of a set of documents and their occurencies. 
The thing is I get a lot of results with numbers that I don't want.
My field is huge string that is provided by my database, initially it's a binary file stored in this database.

I would like to filter those numbers in my request if possible.

```
<!-- text_fr with hunspell -->
  <fieldType name="text_fr_token" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <!-- index analyser -->
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <!-- removes l', etc -->
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" articles="contractions.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!-- voir  si a supprimer  -->
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="1"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            splitOnNumerics="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" format="snowball" />
      <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory"
        dictionary="fr_FR.dic"
        affix="fr_FR.aff"
        ignoreCase="true"
        strictAffixParsing="true"/>
    </analyzer>
 <!--Query analyser-->
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <!-- removes l', etc -->
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" articles="contractions.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!-- voir  si a supprimer  -->
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="0"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="1"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            splitOnNumerics="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" format="snowball" />
      <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory"
        dictionary="fr_FR.dic"
        affix="fr_FR.aff"
        ignoreCase="true"
        strictAffixParsing="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you want to remove numbers from tokens, or remove tokens that are numbers.

To remove numbers from tokens, you could try adding a PatternReplaceFilterFactory to the index analyser section that uses a regular expression to remove digits.

```html
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

To remove tokens that are numbers, you might be able to use one of the Regular Expression Tokenizers as described in the documentation here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwser, the most important for me is to reduce the "cost" of my facet, I know that I won't analyze the numbers of the documents because the goal is to make a cloud tag from this data. So maybe your first idea is the best way to help me, I'll try this and let you know if that works ! :) 

Do you think I need to index again my to check this solution ?

Comment: You'll have to reindex every time you change the indexing definition and expect to use the tokens directly (i.e. for faceting). You also already have a `solr.MappingCharFilterFactory` active, so you could add the numbers to this file to replace them with an empty string as early as possible.